# I am getting this error: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: java, android-studio

Thats my code. I`m getting a lot of error. Help me please, I'm new to
programming java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        AsyncTask<String, Object, StringBuilder> listEmpresasTask = new AsyncTask<String, Object, StringBuilder>() {
            @Override
            protected StringBuilder doInBackground(String... params) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://gsweb-tiagoseibel.rhcloud.com/empresas.json"); //exemplo de conex�o
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String linha;
                    while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(linha);
                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return stringBuilder;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
                super.onPostExecute(stringBuilder);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                try {
                    JSONArray marcas = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < marcas.length(); i++) {
                        String marcaID = marcas.optJSONObject(i).optString("id");
                        String marcaDesc = marcas.optJSONObject(i).optString("descricao");
                        list.add(marcaID + " - " + marcaDesc);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lista de Cooperativas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, list);
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                lv.setAdapter(ad);
            }

        };



    listEmpresasTask.execute();

}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The error :

> 12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:
>   Process: com.example.anderson.myapplication, PID: 2114 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while
>   executing doInBackground() 12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309) 12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission
>   denied (missing INTERNET permission?) 12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:464) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.anderson.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.anderson.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:40)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.system.GaiException:
>   android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with
>   hostname) 12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.anderson.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.anderson.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:40) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)  12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException:
>   android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native
>   Method)  12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.anderson.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.anderson.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:40) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)  12-04 10:44:21.900
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)  12-04
>   10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>   12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)  12-04
>   10:44:22.607 2114-2114/com.example.anderson.myapplication
>   I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread. 12-04 10:44:23.767
>   2114-2123/com.example.anderson.myapplication W/art: Suspending all
>   threads took: 10.982ms 12-04 10:44:24.099
>   2114-2114/com.example.anderson.myapplication W/art: Long monitor
>   contention event with owner method=void
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativeWake(long) from
>   MessageQueue.java:4294967294 waiters=0 for 557ms 12-04 10:44:24.142
>   2114-2135/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/Surface:
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab811e00 12-04 10:44:27.078
>   2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 2114 SIG: 9

Answer (score 2):

you need to add permission in manifest file. From the error you pasted

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) 12-04 10:44:21.900 2114-2134/com.example.anderson.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: at
```

Add proper permission before using internet.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

To your AndroidManifest.xml outside the application tag